# .htaccess remove extension for a single file

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there a possibility to redirect requests for `example.com/test` to `example.com/test.php` for a particular file using `.htaccess`, leaving all other files/extensions intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this : `RewriteRule ^test$ /test.php [L]` place it above your generic redirection written for all site url.

Like for example :

```
RewriteRule ^test$ /test.php [L] --page wise condition 

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L] -- generic for site

RewriteRule ^(.[^\.]*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L] -- generic for site
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test$ test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

All you do is put this right at the beginning of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^test test.php [L]
```

The [L] means it will honor this line and ignore any subsequent lines.

So put all other URL rewrites after this one.